# Как обойти запрет браузера на чтение/изменение css из JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, безопасность

Всем привет!
У меня есть куча 'div'_ов, у которых внешний вид настраивается из классов CSS. Раньше менял с помощью вот такой фунции:

```
function f_changeCSSClass(typeAndClass, newRule, newValue){
    let target = null;
    let ruleSearch = null;
    let thisCSS = document.styleSheets[0];
    console.log(thisCSS.cssRules);
    if(thisCSS.cssRules){
        ruleSearch = thisCSS.cssRules;
        console.log('cssRules');
    }else{
        ruleSearch = thisCSS.rules;
        console.log('rules');
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < ruleSearch.length; i++){
        if(ruleSearch[i].selectorText == typeAndClass){
            target = ruleSearch[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    tagret.style[newRule] = newValue;
}
```

После обновления Chrome до x64 стала выползать ошибка:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
at f_changeCSSClass
```

Почитал - оказывается нельзя теперь вообще, даже, дышать на свойства CSS из JS и любое упоминание .cssRules вызывает ошибку.
Люди добрые, подскажите - как выкрутиться сейчас? Менять всё манулом через `.style` объекта - не вариант, их по 200 штук на странице. Вариант пока приходит в голову один - дописывать в `head` html
Спасибо!

Comment: Добавить CORS и атрибут crossorigin https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804607

Answer (score 1):

Это популярное ошибка которое есть во многих сайтах а чтобы решить данную проблему проста добавьте в начало своих скриптов такой код **crossorigin="anonymous"**